# printf %f address error

Tags: c, printf

I got a problem with printf the pointer address. I was confused with printf.Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  float aa[3] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
  printf("%f, %f\n", aa, aa[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compiled it and got the results like this:

```
2.000000, 1.000000
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What were you expecting? `aa` is not a float...

Comment: "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." -- 7.19.6.1 The fprintf function

Comment: Save time.  Enable all complier warnings which will warn about `float aa[3]; printf("%f, %f\n", aa, ...`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to printf the address,you should use the type of argument that is %p, not %f.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is basically lying (or at least cheating) to your library. If that's intented or by accident doesn't matter.

You tell the library that you want to print a `double` value.
Without knowing the real type, `printf` fetches content for a `double` from the variable parameter list. 
But then you put an address into parameter list which is of wrong type and wrong size.

This does not only mean that the value for this parameter is printed incorrectly, but also that a wrong number of bytes is consumed from the input.

Therefore also the second parameter can be printed incorrectly because `printf` is reading from the wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use %p for printing the address,
Here aa and &aa[0] are both same, which holds the base address of the array.
try this:

```
printf("%p %p",&aa[0],aa); /*Which will give you the base address of array*/
```

You will get the o/p in Hex format.